# Spring 3.x MVC - How can I move by method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, methods, controller, mapping

I looking for a way to find move by method in Spring mvc project.

For instance, I want to go getInfo method in CommonController.java when URL comes "localhost:8080/myproject/common?m=getInfo".

What I did always done is something like below.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/common")
public class CommonController {
  @RequestMapping("/getInfo")
  public ModelAndView getInfo() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Get Information from Common controller");
    return new ModelAndView("index", "model", new Object());
  }
}
```

In this way, I can access to "localhost:8080/common/getInfo". However, what I want to do is access as a parameter. It should be "localhost:8080/common?m=getInfo".

How can I make that? I saw several examples which use MultiActionController. Is the usage same with 3.X version also? Should I add controller to root-context.xml?(which is I really do not want to do :< Can I use just `<context:component-scan>` and other annotations?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `@RequestParam` annotation :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/common")
public class CommonController {

   public ModelAndView getInfo(@RequestParam("m") String param) throws Exception {
   if("getInfo".equals(param)){
       //your code
   }
}
```

OR directly with `@RequestMapping`

```
@Controller
public class CommonController {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/common", params = "m=getInfo")
   public ModelAndView getInfo() throws Exception {
       //your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works nice. however, can I set MethodNameResolver with code, not xml configuration?

Comment: @JuneyoungOh It will help me if you provide more details, that is what exactly do you want to acomplish. From what I understand from your question, you could use `@RequestMapping(value="/common" , params = "m=XXXXX")` on your methods if you want to avoid xml configuration

Comment: I can accomplish exactly what I want to do with your answer. However, if I use like that, every time I should put "m=XXXX". The parameter name "m" is so fixed so I want to make it as a pattern. In spring 2.x way, I can put "p:methodNameResolver" in the bean declaration in xml. So I think we can just write that pattern("m=") once somewhere and works same.  I am asking this since I do not know it is possible or not.

Comment: I do not know if it's possible but I would not combine Spring's annotations with xml configuration files, because it will make it harder to track on on future. If I'd like that parameter name to be easy to modify on future , I would create a constant and use that constant all over the places. E.g. : `public static final String PARAM_NAME= "m" ` , and then  `@RequestMapping(value="/common" , params = PARAM_NAME + "=XXXXXX")` . Or even further , you may create a properties file and load the constant from that file in a static way .

Comment: Thanks I should use '@RequestMapping(params)' this time :D